# Installing packages in multiple systems

Tags: package-management

I have to install some packages in 5 Ubuntu system in my office. There, bandwidth is limited. So, is there any way to install it in one system & copy to other, so that all works fine? All systems are fresh install.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe not an exact duplicate but the solutions for "[How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)" should help you.

Since bandwidth is an issue you might also want to consider setting up one of the machines as a [caching deb proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan) so you don't have to manually copy files around, that way if you install a package once it will be cached on your LAN.

Answer (score 3):

Simply copy the relevant deb archives from `/var/cache/apt/archives` of the first machine to `/var/cache/apt/archives` of every machine

Then run the same installation command given on the first machine on every other machine.

If already there, deb archives will not be downloaded, and only installation take place.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use aptoncd.
This will create an iso image for you containing an offline repository of all the apps installed on the first computer.
You could then use the aptoncd on the other 5 computers to copy the apps to cache for Software Center to use or add the cd as a repository to synaptic package manager.