# Repository Package Transfer

Tags: package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing packages in multiple systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5440/installing-packages-in-multiple-systems)

Is it possible to easily transfer one PC's packages into another one either over a network, but mainly through usb or dvd-rom medias? In another words, to duplicate or copy the installed packages into another one (think, Copy/Paste).

Answer (score 1):

Try [aptoncd](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/aptoncd). This might be what you're looking for. Doesn't do deb's I think.

Comment: I tried this once, burned the image into an iso, it didn't boot from it.  I guess it can be used as a backup, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. you can copy the debs contained in the folder `/var/cache/apt/archives` and paste it into the target pc's folder.

Know that this will only copy the debs. Installation of the softwares will have to be done manually through software center or through synaptic.

Comment: This seems fine, I'll try it today. Thanks for your immediate response.  I'll let you know. Take care!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a copy of your setup you could follow the first post from this link,

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=261366

However you will need internet access.

If you don't have internet access on the second PC, and the packages are no longer present on the first machine, do a download only and then copy the files across using a USB stick.

sudo apt-get --download-only packagename