# Multiple installations

Tags: installation, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing packages in multiple systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5440/installing-packages-in-multiple-systems)

We are planning to install around 15 machines with desktop version and we need same software on all machine. Can you suggest best approach to save time? We are not much technical and we install software by going to software manager, we just need to avoid this as it takes lots of time to download all software each time.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to to?

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate. Check the solution by Mitch...

Comment: In my opinion this is not a duplicate: The other question was about saving bandwidth; this one is about having identical systems and saving time.

Comment: After the initial installation, you may considering enabling the ssh daemon (apt get openssh-server) so you can log in remotely, you can run all the "apt" commands centrally without physically going to the machine.  This allows you to install, upgrade and remove software remotely.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to install an OS, and other software clone it, and install the same exact on 15 machines.  If that's the case, the you can use clonezilla. There is a limitation of (The destination partition must be equal or larger than the source one).

> Clonezilla is a partition or disk clone tool similar to Norton Ghost®.
>   It saves and restores only used blocks in hard drive. Two types of
>   Clonezilla are available: Clonezilla live and Clonezilla SE (Server
>   Edition).  While Clonezilla SE is for massive deployment, it can clone
>   many (40 plus!) computers simultaneously. Clonezilla saves and
>   restores only used blocks in the harddisk.<sup>1</sup>

You can [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/files/latest/download) clonezilla, burn it to a CD, and you're ready to roll.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Clonezilla](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/)</sup>

Comment: Love the Clonezilla  I must try now

Answer (score 0):

You can first download all the *.deb files and the dependencies. Then you can install them in all computers by the command:-

> sudo dpkg -i filename_1.deb filename_2.deb

Here filename_1.deb and filename_2.deb represent the files that you have downloaded. This will save your downloading time but the installing time will remain the same!

Answer (score 0):

If the software are available in the official Ubuntu 12.04 repository, 
you can easily download them via command line like so

**example**:

```
sudo apt-get --download-only install firefox
```

`sudo` means give root(admin) right to a user/application and you need to give a password

`apt-get` is the program that downloads and or install the applications

and when downloaded, run this command to install them silently

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```