# How do I set up my own local update repository?

Tags: repository, mirrors

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is it possible to mirror the apt repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9809/is-it-possible-to-mirror-the-apt-repositories)
>   [How to set up an APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository)

Can I construct a local repository , and manage updates for other ubuntu-desktop remotely ??

If yes, could you help me with the steps?

Comment: posible duplicated -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/9809/is-it-possible-to-mirror-the-apt-repositories and http://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository