# Firewall wont let me through but I can copy the files using another machine

Tags: apt

Very new to Ubuntu so please bear with me

I am building a server using Ubuntu 12.04
The firewall will not let me through to do any APT-GET's or updates
Can I copy the files needed and put them on the server and point the sourses file to that location to do the updates that way?
If I can what files do I copy

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Look at these questions. [question 1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline), [question 2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9809/is-it-possible-to-mirror-the-apt-repositories) and [question 3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan). If you think, those question have solutions for your problem, let us know. If not, edit your question saying how those question didn't help you. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about apt-get but at least you can install the desired packages manually via `dpkg`. Though you will need to resolve all dependencies yourself.