# Random idle time out Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: desktop-environments, mate, .desktop, system-settings, ubuntu-mate

Would like to seek some inputs with regards to Mate's (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS) behavior of having random idle time outs.

Problem: Observing idle timeout intervals of 10s, 20s, 30s, 40s randomly. "Dim display when idle" is ticked in the Mate Power Management Preferences.

Tshoot steps made (updated):

- Tried using "gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-time 60" but idle-dim-time is not initially listed from org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.gschema.xml (https://askubuntu.com/questions/9818...le-dim-timeout)
- Added idle-dim-time from the step above and initially applied 10s value but still getting random idle times
- Edited via dconf editor GUI for newly added idle-dim-time but still has random idle times
- Upgraded to Mate 1.16.2 desktop, idle-dim-time values seem to be doubling for every screen dim

All help would be highly appreciated!