# Would there be any negative side-effects of sharing /var/cache/apt/ between two systems?

Tags: virtualbox, apt, bandwidth, cache

In the interest of conserving bandwidth, I'm considering mounting a VirtualBox host's `/var/cache/apt` as `/var/cache/apt` in the guest. Both host and guest are Ubuntu 10.10 32-bit. Would there be any negative consequences to doing this?

I'm aware of the more robust solutions like apt-proxy, but I'd prefer this simpler solution if it's possible in order to spare the host the overhead of running extra services.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that `/var/cache/apt/{,src}pkgcache.bin` contains the current installed packages.

Instead of sharing `/var/cache/apt/`, share the `/var/cache/apt/archives/` directory, which contains independent files. You have to do some tweaking, because `/var/cache/apt/archives` is owned and writable only by root. One option would be setting the group of `/var/cache/apt/archives` to `apt-cache-writer` and adding the setgid bit to the directory. Add yourself to the `apt-cache-writer` group and set the `umask` to something like `0002` or `0007` instead of `0022`.

Note that `sudo apt-get clean` clears this directory (`/var/cache/apt/archives`).

Comment: On Ubuntu 14 I tried this to find that the exclusive apt lock is based on a file in this directory! (What!? a lock file in a cache directory!) So sharing the literal file system with a VM or the like may not be a good solution. I would too recommend using a proper apt-caching service, discussed in detail here: http://askubuntu.com/q/3503/250556

Answer (score 4):

Rather than share that folder, will be more "healty" create a LAN repository using APT-CACHER

[here 's](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Create-a-LAN-Repository-with-Apt-Cacher-45978.shtml)  a tutorial about that software

Comment: A downside of this approach is that VirtualBox will consume more disk space. This should not be a problem if you have a 1TB HDD, but with small SSDs, it is.

Answer (score 4):

Your best solution is to use Apt-Cacher-NG on the host machine. You don't need to worry about dedicating a networked computer for aptcacher because it runs as a simple program with a simple instalation/configuration. The only think to watch out for is the amount of disk space you have fee but I have been using this setup for quite a while so far and it hasn't been a problem.

It may seem odd but you can also use apt-cacher for the machine that apt-cacher is installed on. This means that if your VM updates before your host it will populate the cache and the Host will be able to get the package from the cache.

You will also be able to see statistics of how much is being cached and what the hit rate is by putting the url: "http://your-apt-cacher-ng-server:3142" in your browser (see below).

A good simple explanation of how to configure the apt-cacher can be found here: http://acidborg.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/how-to-install-and-configure-apt-cacher-ng-on-ubuntu-server-10-04/ which I will paste below for completeness.

1. Installation: `apt-get install apt-cacher-ng`
2. Configuration: Edit `/etc/apt-cacher-ng/acng.conf` with the following content:

> ```
> CacheDir: /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng
> LogDir: /var/log/apt-cacher-ng
> Port:3142
> BindAddress: 0.0.0.0
> Remap-debrep: file:deb_mirror*.gz /debian ; file:backends_debian
> Remap-uburep: file:ubuntu_mirrors /ubuntu ; file:backends_ubuntu
> PidFile: /var/run/apt-cacher-ng/pid
> ExTreshold: 4
> ```

1. Restart Apt-Cacher NG: `/etc/init.d/apt-cacher-ng restart`
2. Create on the rest of the Debian/Ubuntu machines on the network the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy` with the following content:

   `Acquire::http { Proxy "http://your-apt-cacher-ng-server:3142"; };`

Comment: Before wasting an afternoon on one particular piece of apt caching software (as I did), I recommend reading up on http://askubuntu.com/q/3503/250556  - I've had the *least* problems with `squid-deb-proxy`, neither apt-cacher (gross perl blob) or apt-cacaher-ng (nicer python mess with config files) worked very well  for me on 14.04 LTS near the timestamp of this message.