# Create local repo for some applications

Tags: server

i have try to search over the internet but got nothing

this is my situation,

i have more than 30 vps running ubuntu server 12.04

i need to install openssh, webserver (apache + php) & database server (mysql) to all of this vps.

unfortunately, my bandwidth is limited

my question is :
how to create **local repo that contain needed application only** so my other vps don't need internet connection to install this application ?

looking forward for your response

Comment: seems that you need [apt-cacher](http://askubuntu.com/q/46534/169736)