# How to have a server the makes a clients update and download software offline?

Tags: networking, server, proxy, apt-mirror

I guess I have to make a proxy server to be able the clients update and download offline.
**But how? Any ideas.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this is to use apt-cacher.

[How to set up an apt-cacher server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46534/how-to-set-up-an-apt-cacher-server)

You may also use apt-mirror.

Thanks