# Failed to move *.deb to /var/cache/apt-cacher/packages/*.deb: Permission denied

Tags: apt-cacher

I followed following post [How to set up an apt-cacher server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46534/how-to-set-up-an-apt-cacher-server), but having this error:

```
got@got-mypc:/var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo /usr/share/apt-cacher/apt-cacher-import.pl        /var/cache/apt/archives/
    Importing from /var/cache/apt/archives/
    Moving package files from /var/cache/apt/archives/ to /var/cache/apt-cacher
    Importing: account-plugin-facebook_0.8-0ubuntu2.2_i386.deb
    Failed to move account-plugin-facebook_0.8-0ubuntu2.2_i386.deb to /var/cache/apt-cacher/packages/account-plugin-facebook_0.8-0ubuntu2.2_i386.deb: Permission denied.
    Try read-only (-r) or symlink (-l) options. at /usr/share/apt-cacher/apt-cacher-import.pl line 364.
```

Why facebook error since i haven't installed any plugins for fb atleast by myself. Also i tried this using root login but didn't work. How to solve this now.

Comment: What are the permissions on the offending `deb`... what does `ls -al /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-facebook_0.8-0ubuntu2.2_i386.deb` show for owner, read/write permissions?  If you don't use the plugin, you could just remove the file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options.

1. Use the read only option:

   ```
   sudo /usr/share/apt-cacher/apt-cacher-import.pl -r /var/cache/apt/archives/
   ```
2. Use the symlink option:

   ```
   sudo /usr/share/apt-cacher/apt-cacher-import.pl -l /var/cache/apt/archives/
   ```
3. Remove the offending package and try again:

   ```
   sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-facebook_0.8-0ubuntu2.2_i386.deb to /var/cache/apt-cacher/packages/account-plugin-facebook_0.8-0ubuntu2.2_i386.deb
   sudo /usr/share/apt-cacher/apt-cacher-import.pl /var/cache/apt/archives/
   ```