# Local server updates for the network

Tags: 11.04, server, upgrade, updates, files

I have setup one computer on our network as the file server. Because Internet here in Tanzania is both slow and expensive I would like that one system to download all the updates and then the other 10 computers on the network to get those update files from the server. I'm a bit of a noobie to Ubuntu, but really want to learn how to get this working smoothly so as to help other NGOs and schools here in Tanzania. Brendon

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to cache apt downloads on a LAN?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan)

Answer (score 1):

Great news, this is a simple setup.

1) On the system you want to host all of the files, install "squid-deb-proxy"

2) On all of the systems (including the system from step 1), install "squid-deb-proxy-client"

That's it, now all of your clients will use the one system to get updates/install packages, and if that system doesn't have the file it (the server) will go out and get the file.

Answer (score 0):

On your server, install the package [apt-cacher-ng](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/apt-cacher-ng).

If you have a firewall, open port 3142 to client machines.

On each client, run

```
 echo "Acquire::http { Proxy \"http://<serveripaddress>:3142\"; };" | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy
```

to enable the caching.

If you need to disable caching on a client for some reason, you can simply run

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy
```