# Apply Ubuntu in university

Tags: drivers, system-installation, client

I work in project to apply ubuntu client in all computer in my university .
can you help my to know the steps to do it?

Comment: The question might need more details on the situation, requirements, possibilities, impossibilities. It would be better to first investigate and then ask (a) specific question(s).

Comment: Have you seen this thread?  It can get you started until you have more specific questions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/249728/how-to-set-up-a-computer-lab-for-a-school

Answer (score 1):

Never done it, but this is where I'd start.

**If the hardware is unique to each machine:**

1. Install Ubuntu.
2. Install proprietary graphics card drivers (people will suggest using the open source ones, but ignore them.)
3. Test to see that your hardware works (eg: sound, networking).
4. If any hardware doesn't work then search for info online about needed drivers, and install if available.
5. Install desired programs. To avoid having to redownload on each computer copy the apt cache contents to each machine and use the apt command that tells apt to install from the cache.
6. Create a user account with heavy restrictions, for people to use. [Unless you're desiring some kind of across systems login? Can't help with that.]

**If hardware is identical**

1. Use previous steps, and then use DD to clone to the other systems. [If you're planning on networking the computers you might want to change their system names after cloning.]