# sudo apt-get trying to connect through old proxy

Tags: networking, apt, proxy

I previously had a proxy set-up when visiting somewhere for work, to use the internet there. I have since returned, and I thought got rid of the proxy.

However today when I try to run

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y flashplugin-installer
```

It tries to connect through the proxy:

```
 Unable to connect to wwwout.nims.go.jp:8888
```

Any ideas how to get rid of this?

I have removed all the references to the proxy from the network connections, and also deleted the references to the proxy in /etc/environment

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `apt` uses its own proxy configuration: have a look at this similar issue [cannot update unless on one network](http://askubuntu.com/a/576744/178692)

Answer (score 1):

Just found it.

Deleting the lines containing the proxy in:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf
```

sorted it.