# Setting no proxy, proxy and Authenticating network from terminal

Tags: command-line, networking, apt, proxy, display-manager

Somehow I can not access my desktop and have access to command-line. I can ONLY see wallpaper after login (no icons), I think I messed up with lightdm. Other posts suggests that I can reconfigure it or reinstall it by accessing Terminal(Ctrl+ Alt+ F1) and here comes the main problem:

I am using University's network for accessing internet, which requires proxy setting and authentication. Earlier for updating Ubuntu I use to set no-proxy in Firefox and then apt-get, but now I can not access Firefox itself. In addition to no-proxy, University have many other proxy options. I tried to set a few of the alternate proxies through:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port
```

pinging google.com results in no connection (100% loss), but I can successfully ping the proxy server. I don't know how to connect through no-proxy in Terminal. Can any one suggest me how to bring back the display manager or to manage the proxy setting? Thanks.

Comment: try executing this in terminal sudo dkpg-reconfigure -a

Comment: The correct command should be: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`, but then there is this error: `Unknown option: a`

Comment: I'm not quite clear what your issue is, however you should be able to specify a proxy for apt-get itself on the command line e.g. `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::Proxy=<host> update` to use proxy `<host>` or `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::Proxy=false update` to use a direct (non-proxied) connection. See [cannot update unless on one network](http://askubuntu.com/a/576744/178692) or `man apt.conf` for details.

Comment: see my post here: http://askubuntu.com/a/707754/476968