# Unable to use sudo apt-get update on my terminal. Unable to install applications or update system because of it

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

I do not know the root cause that may have triggered this ( it happened recently). I have by all means looked at the questions with similar problem[image], however even though some have had same problems and got solutions I am unable to get the same result. I am only a beginner hence I do properly understand certain aspects taken for granted in solutions such as gaining root privileges to modify a /etc/apt/sources.list with certain lines.

Please walk me through What I sould be doing.

Comment: Looks like a misconfigured proxy - btw, please don't post screenshots of text

Comment: Ok. Please tell me how to set it right?

Comment: I'd start by trying `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::Proxy=false update` as explained [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/576744/178692)

Comment: Hey I ran it. It did successfully execute. However the sudo apt-get update still does not!

Comment: I could run only step 1 in the given link. Step2 couldnt be executed as i was not allowed to modify any files and i cant download synaptic package manager because apt-get is not working.