# apt-get update errors immediately after yakkety update

Tags: apt, 16.10

...as mentioned in title. The errors are:

```
Err:107 http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/ubuntu yakkety-security/main amd64 Packages
  Sub-process ProxyAutoDetect returned an error code (100)
```

and

```
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Little info on googles about this.

I've tried changing the repo servers, same issue with any I try.

I've also tried disabling ipv6, no avail.

Any ideas what I can do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you **purge** the `squid-deb-proxy` package or did you just remove it with apt? The latter does remove the package but not the entire configuration. Some parts of the configuration may still be active, you can remove them with `sudo dpkg -P squid-deb-proxy`.

The corresponding config files can be found in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

---

You can regenerate your apt sources list at https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ and then replace your default `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I would also make a copy of your /etc/apt/sources* for future references, and to possibly get an idea what went wrong there.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried this, but I got the same errors.

Comment: Could you try again and leaving out the canonical one (Partner and/or Extra ?) for the moment ? And change to another mirror in your country or from a near by country ? Maybe your local mirror has a temporary problem ? And have you been using any apt proxy like apt-cacher-ng or approx or the like in the past maybe ?

Comment: As I mentioned, I've tried several different repo servers. I have used squid-deb-proxy a long time ago, but not for a few years. Not sure how I'd diagnose that. I think the problem is maybe more linked to that idea (I was just considering that as a possibility, but not sure how to pursue that).

Comment: All apt config regarding repositories would be in /etc/apt/  For things like apt-cacher-ng one would add a file with proxy settings in the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ folder. Did you purge the squid-deb-proxy package ? (sudo apt-get remove package name does remove the package but not the system config part) Maybe some config parts are still there. sudo dpkg -P squid-deb-proxy would remove the old config as well.

Comment: Dude, you're awesome. sudo dpkg -P squid-deb-proxy-client is what did it. If you put this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Great that you got it solved now. I was about to install 16.10 from a mini iso (55Mb) because I got curious where the problem was exactly. Cheers.

Comment: I'm serious, make an answer (or edit this to append the answer) and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm brand new here. I've added it in the first answer now.

Comment: I just got the same error message and couldn't find the left over configuration after removing squid-deb-proxy that triggered the ProxyAutoDetect message after looking at the packages [file listing](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/all/squid-deb-proxy/filelist). With `grep -i proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*` I knew where to look for. let's see if we can improve this answer further.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer may be correct in some cases, for example in my case I did not touch `squid-deb-proxy` (or anything `squid`) as this happened.

One possible reason for this (at least this was my problem under `bionic`) the way the detection script uses `nc`.
It does simply `nc -z $host $port`, but if `$host:$port` does not exist, `nc` will try forever (or for some very long time), and `ProxyAutoDetect` will fail. (Interestingly the detect script worked under `xenial`.)
The solution is to set the timeout (`-w $INTEGER`) on `nc`, so it times out faster than `ProxyAutoDetect` and can try the next proxy.

To find the script you could try to look after its path in the files under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

Note: the script I am using is a slightly modified version of the script posted here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53443/how-do-i-ignore-a-proxy-if-not-available.