# squid-deb-proxy on client side unable to get packages from the server

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, apt, squid, squid-deb-proxy

I am having 2 laptops on one of them I did a do-release-upgrade 
and it took near about 10 hours to upgrade to 12.04

now I want to upgrade second laptop also so I used following thread

[Best way to cache apt downloads on a LAN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan)

I installed on the laptop (which was upgraded to 12.04 to be used as caching server so that packages are not downloaded again)

```
sudo apt-get install squid-deb-proxy avahi-utils
```

started the service

```
 sudo start squid-deb-proxy
```

and `cp /var/cache/apt/archives/* /var/cache/squid-deb-proxy/`

on the client I installed

```
sudo apt-get install squid-deb-proxy-client
```

now on the client I do a `sudo do-release-upgrade`

but it fails to get any kind of upgrade from the deb-proxy-server
and rather connects to internet and this is taking 8-10 hours of time for
 upgrade process.
This is verified by the logs on server which mention

```
1358365800.075    337 192.168.1.3 TCP_MISS/304 282 GET http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages.bz2 - DIRECT/91.189.88.33 -
1358365800.119    338 192.168.1.3 TCP_MISS/304 360 GET http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/source/Sources.bz2 - DIRECT/91.189.91.15 -
```

TCP_MISS which should be rather TCP_HIT
so the squid-deb-proxy server is not working properly.Here what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just copy debs into the squid-deb-proxy directory as those are stored as squid objects, so that probably won't work.

- [How to add packages to a squid-deb-proxy cache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111892/how-to-add-packages-to-a-squid-deb-proxy-cache)

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way you can do this unless you would have install squid-deb-proxy server and client on your laptop *before* it was upgraded, so it could have cached the debs prior to the upgrade on the first laptop.