# Where are apt-get files stored?

Tags: apt

There are multiple virtual machines running Ubuntu and they are all updated by the following command:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

But updating each VM separately takes a lot of time to download the required packages and also uses massive amount of bandwidth (which I'm running out of). Is it possible to transfer the updated files by `apt-get` directly into VMs?

I know the packages are stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives` but I need the apt-get database files (list of mirrors, indexes, available packages on mirrors, ...)

---

Update: There are many solutions

1. apt-cacher-ng as mentioned in the answers.
2. Docker images built for caching apt files (they run squid actually)
3. Simply using squid

Also, as mentioned in the answers, see [Best way to cache apt downloads on a LAN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan)

Comment: You can use `apt-config dump` to print the config to the screen. The entry you want is `Dir::Cache`. The values build up on their parent entries. So you need to look at `Dir` to get context for the value of `Dir::Cache`. On my system its `/var/cache/apt/`. It's also possible to query individual entries. I didnt look into how to do that though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not an explicit answer to your question, but have you considered setting up an apt proxy? I use apt-cacher-ng (apt-get install apt-cacher-ng). Prehaps set this up on the VM host, and tell the VMs (and the host) to use this as their proxy (as simple as adding a file (eg `02proxy`) to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`
containing

```
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://vm host ip:3142"; };
```

That way you can just do `apt-get upgrade` without having to manually copy file around. When one computer downloads the debs they will be stored on the proxy for the next computer that requests it. Can handle multiple releases and different architectures, etc

Comment: You can even install `squid-deb-proxy` on the proxy server and `squid-deb-proxy-client` on others; this will make the proxy detection work transparently (using Avahi), no client-side configuration required. As a bonus, if the proxy server is not found on the local network, the client will connect to the repositories directly (making this suitable even for laptops).

Comment: I second the use of Squid-deb-proxy over Apt-cacher. Relevant Q: [Best way to cache apt downloads on a LAN?](http://askubuntu.com/q/3503/88802)

Answer (score 50):

The .deb-files you have allready downloaded are stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.

Comment: Oooh, beat me by 26 seconds :)

Comment: That's why I have twice as much reputation ;-P

Comment: Oooooohhhh, burrrrn. :)

Comment: …and the apt repository-info cache files are stored at `/var/lib/apt/`, FTR.

Answer (score 17):

`/var/cache/apt/archives` is where they should be stored.

Answer (score 1):

Quick instructions to create a local apt archive using a convenient debian tool called "apt-ftparchive"

Example, create /home/aptcache as local directory to store *.deb files to install in future without repeat download and wasting bandwidth:

```
# Create the directory

  mkdir /home/aptcache

# Copy debs already downloaded to your system:

  cp /var/cache/apt/archives/* /home/aptcache/

# Scan the local packages into local database

  cd /home/atpcache
  apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages
  apt-ftparchive release . > Release

# Add this line to /etc/apt/sources.list (I placed at top)

  deb [allow-insecure=yes] file:/home/aptcache ./

# Update apt

  apt-get update
```

Now you can install the package normally. If apt-get asks "Install these packages without verification?", answer "Y" to install. That's because this local repository is not signed.

You can also install all packages in your new local apt archive in one simple command

```
  apt-get install aptcache
```

source information: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Setup#Quick_instructions_to_create_a_trivial_local_archive_with_apt-ftparchive

(acknowledgement to Debian team!)

Answer (score 0):

You can backup all the *.deb, then copy it into vmware, you can copy it in `/root/sw_backup`. The folder can not be `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.

Then you can locally install it with synaptic.
$synaptic 
"file" menu to find local install.
but it also needs network, just need to update a little package.

Comment: Please note this should be .deb not .dep