# Re-install a set of deb files on another machine without re-downloading

Tags: installation, apt, cache

I made a setup for development, and it downloaded a large set of .deb files. Now, I want to re-do this for a presentation, but I do not want to re-download the 400 files live. That would take too long. How can I get those files copied to `/var/cache/apt` and quickly reinstall them from local files. Will having the files locally avoid the download ?

Comment: You might be interested in this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/3503/2355

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply copy the files to the other machine and they will not need downloaded again.  You might use `scp` to copy files over the network if you have an ssh server installed.