# How to tell if squid-deb-proxy is working?

Tags: cache, squid, squid-deb-proxy

I've got squid-deb-proxy, avahi-tools, and squid-deb-proxy-client installed on a gateway VM running 12.04 Server, and squid-deb-proxy-client installed on two client VMs running Lubuntu and Xubuntu 12.04.

The service appears to be up and running according to htop, and I can see considerable activity when the clients update/upgrade, and I see activity in the log files... but I'm not seeing any cache being stored in /var/spool/squid3 - or anywhere else.

What should I be looking for to tell if its really working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logs on the server will show you if it's working, see here:

- [Best way to cache apt downloads on a LAN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan)

Comment: I've updated that answer with the file system location of the files.

Comment: Please take a look at the `sudo start squid-deb-proxy-avahi` line in that other thread... it does not appear to work in 12.04 LTS.