# How do I download all the Proprietary drivers for offline use?

Tags: drivers, repository, wget

In what repository do the Proprietary drivers that are found on the Additional Drivers window found and how can I copy them all so I can have them stored in case I find myself in a computer with a proprietary need but no internet access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Recursive download from here: `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/`
- e.g. `wget -nH -np --cut-dirs=3 -r -l0 $URL`
- where `$URL` is above or your favorite mirror.

Answer (score 0):

They're in the `Restricted`repository.

When you download them and don't clean the cache they're stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

You can also download the packages from http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Thanks Uri. Also wanted to know how to download them all, can't navigate easily in the link you provided to the restricted drivers.

Comment: This possibly could help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan