# How to download once and update all computers?

Tags: networking, repository, deb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)
>   [Best way to cache apt downloads on a LAN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan)

maybe this will be a duplicate post, but I've found nothing.
I work at a school, in the Computer Lab we have 8 computers and I installed Ubuntu on them. We have classes each wednesday, so the problem that we have is that each week all the computers have updates to install. If I update all the computers, the internet goes terribly slow, because the use of bandwidth (we have a 5MB connection only).
Is there a way to download the pakages once in a computer and the rest of the computers grab the files from it? Also, if a file is not in the principal computer, it can be downloaded from the Internet.
I've seen that is possible to use aptproxy, but the idea is not to have all the repositories in the computer, only the ones we use (when we run updates or install programs)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1st you have download APTonCD package.
this package will help you to create .iso image file of which you have download from internet.
after creating image file,image file content or packages are ready to install other machine.

Answer (score 0):

apt-proxy does what you're asking for.  It doesn't get files you don't need, as you seem to think.

From the description:
[`"It builds up a partial Debian mirror, containing those files which have been requested by clients."`](http://apt-proxy.sourceforge.net/)

I used to run it, when I needed that service, and was very happy with it.  It did its job, and I didn't have to think about it much, as I remember.

However, it looks unmaintained now; it isn't in current Ubuntu or Debian.  The packages `apt-cacher` and `approx` are replacements.  I haven't used them myself.  It's not a terribly difficult job, and it sounds like they have replaced apt-proxy satisfactorily.

[This article from Linux Weekly News](https://lwn.net/Articles/318658/) covers the topic, but is three years old.  You could check that out, though it probably goes into more alternatives than you need.  I think the odds are good that if you try `apt-cacher` and/or `approx` you'll get what you want.