# will squid-deb-proxy be used for release upgrades?

Tags: upgrade, apt, squid, squid-deb-proxy

I am in the process of updating a bunch of machines to 12.xx.

For regular package updates I tried **apt-proxy**, which had random hiccups (clients hanging on various headers). Now I installed **apt-cacher-ng**, but that seems not to work when running `do-release-upgrade` (I'm guessing because the special update-info does not match some URL pattern of apt-cacher-ng):

```
user@machine:~# sudo do-release-upgrade --proposed
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Failed Upgrade tool signature
Done Upgrade tool
Done downloading
authenticate 'lucid.tar.gz' against 'lucid.tar.gz.gpg'
exception from gpg: GnuPG exited non-zero, with code 131072
Debug information:


gpg: can't open `/tmp/tmpJCfO-a/lucid.tar.gz.gpg'
gpg: verify signatures failed: file open error

Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

Now I read about **squid-deb-proxy** and the dynamic broadcasting seems neat, especially since we have notebooks in our office.

Will that proxy work with **do-release-upgrade** or should I set up my own Squid altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, squid-deb-proxy works with do-release-upgrades, I recommend doing one machine first to "seed" the cache, then you should be good to go.

See also:

- [Best way to cache apt downloads on a LAN?](https://askubuntu.com/q/3503/235)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just tried it and according to the access.log the squid-deb-proxy is getting utilized during do-release-upgrade. Thanks!