# using the downloaded upgrade packages from one laptop to another

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, upgrade, apt, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

I have upgraded Ubuntu 11.10 (amd64) to 12.04 (amd64)  on one of the laptops I have,
I have another laptop which is also running 11.10 (amd64)  I want to use the packages downloaded on the first laptop on the second 
laptop so that both have Ubuntu 12.04 
 I checked on first laptop (now running 12.04 ) downloaded upgrades are residing in `/var/cache/apt/archives`
I  have done an sftp for those packages from laptop 1 to laptop 2.

On the laptop 2 I have  tried putting those package files into
`/var/apt/cache/archives`
and then just firing the upgrade process `do-release-upgrade`,
 and unfortunately this does not work and rather than picking the packages from
`/var/cache/apt/archives`

it goes to some thing like

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main qemu-utils amd64 1.0+noroms-0ubuntu13 [353 kB]
```

and so on and is downloading things,

Now what I want to know is how do I make sure do-release-upgrade uses these in my laptop and does not downloads 700 mb of updates because this will take 8-10 hours at my end so I want to utilize the upgrades which were downloaded during the upgrade process
on one of the systems.
If there is a way in this situation let me know.

Comment: Not an answer for your issue right now, but for next time: [Best way to cache apt downloads on a LAN?](http://askubuntu.com/q/3503/88802)

Comment: May I remind you to eventually accept some answers (to other questions :-) ?

Answer (score 0):

I love this trick. It should work fine. Perhaps the files are owned by the wrong user. What I do is first install an ssh server on the machine with updates. `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

The copy them into place from the other machine:

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
sudo scp <user>@<machine with updates>:/var/cache/apt/archives/* .
```

The dot tells scp to put them in the current directory.

Comment: No this does not work I already did that and inspite of having them done an scp to current machines /var/cache/apt/archives it will still connect to internet to download the packages the presence of packages in /var/cache/apt/archives had no difference at all

Comment: Maybe there is something about the user or permissions of those files. With the sudo as I did it worked fine for me, they were not downloaded again and were installed correctly. Not sure what is different from your configuration compared to the ones I have done successfully.