# Howto use apt-cacher-ng only when available?

Tags: apt, proxy, apt-cacher-ng

I'm using `apt-cacher-ng` at my local network with the following configuration on the clients:

```
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://acng-host:3142"; };
```

Some of the clients are laptops, so how do I configure them to use the cache only when it's available on this network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

**/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d**

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=10.0.1.13
port=3142
nc -w 1 $ip $port
proxy_file="/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02local_proxy"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Acquire::http { Proxy \"http://$ip:$port\"; };" > $proxy_file
    echo 'Acquire::https { Proxy "false"; };' >> $proxy_file
else
    rm -f $proxy_file
fi
```

**Fix permissions**

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99SetAptProxy
```

**Notes:**

- The "nc" command tests that it can connect to the 3142 port on the given IP address.
- This script is run everytime the networking interfaces are changed by network manager.
- Feel free to alter the *way* that you detect for the proxy, this works for me, but it is a security vulnerability if you install packages on a foreign network, for example.

Answer (score 7):

From the **server** you can announce to the network there is an apt-cacher-ng instance through avahi

From the **client** you can check if exist an apt-cacher-ng service and modify apt proxy settings accordly.

---

## Server

Install

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-cacher-ng squid-deb-proxy-client
```

For Ubuntu releases older than 14.04 put the following snippet in /etc/avahi/services/apt-cacher-ng.service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
 <name replace-wildcards="yes">apt-cacher-ng proxy on %h</name>
 <service protocol="ipv4">
  <type>_apt_proxy._tcp</type>
  <port>3142</port>
 </service>
</service-group>
```

## Client

Install

```
$ sudo apt-get install squid-deb-proxy-client
```

---

Here is a snippet to install server|client depending if there is already an apt-get proxy or not:

- https://gist.github.com/chilicuil/6207489

Source: http://blog.surgut.co.uk/2013/03/avahi-apt-cacher-ng-sbuild.html

Comment: That's a nice find! I'm wondering why this isn't the default whenever apt-cacher-ng is suggested, [Dimitri John Ledkov](https://launchpad.net/~xnox) has a canonical.com address and the snippet is already included in [14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/apt-cacher-ng/filelist). I just made an edit your answer.

Comment: So the magic on 18.04 appears to be in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/30autoproxy`, which contains the single line: `Acquire::http::ProxyAutoDetect "/usr/share/squid-deb-proxy-client/apt-avahi-discover";` (referring to a Python script). Sweet. This gets installed by `squid-deb-proxy-client`. So for my own scenario I don't need that on the server _at all_!

Answer (score -1):

Not an exact answer, since you'll have to change your existing cache setup, but `squid-deb-proxy` is a good solution to providing a cache that will be used transparently if available, and is very easy to set up on both cache server and clients. See the [first answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan/25945) for more details.

Comment: ... that was hopefully meant to be "that will be used transparently if available and if `avahi` is installed on the client side" ;)