# How does squid-deb-proxy handle older/newer versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, squid-deb-proxy

I followed Jorge Castro thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan)
and its working without a problem! on 12.04-2 x64 bit. However I have a question:

If there is an old/newer version client of ubuntu. How does it fetch cached updates?

Comment: Please ask the proxy authentication question as a seperate question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proxy works by caching the files themselves, so if you have an older version of Ubuntu and a newer version, most likely they will not share the same files.

So if you have 12.04 and 12.10, the cache will keep the files for each distro and will not share the .debs (except in the rare cases where a .deb goes from one release to the next without being changed). Usually if you have more than one of each version at a location that doesn't really matter as having a cache will still be better than none at all, but if you have an office with say one 10.04, one 12.04, one Debian, and one 13.04, then it'll keep a set of packages for each of those.

Though having cache misses for those can seem bad, it is nice when you have to upgrade an older machine and your proxy already has the files for the next version ready to go.

Also of note, the architecture matters, so if you have 64 bit 12.04 and 32 bit 12.04 the only .debs cached that will be applicable to both will be packages with data and documentation which are not architecture specific will be cached.

Comment: Oke thanks Jorge for the answer. But the thing is that I am setting up an ubuntu 12.04-x64bit and I want squid-deb-proxy server to be installed on it and client of course to retrieve the packages. But it will only retrieve and downloads packages for the ubuntu 12.04 x64 bit version only and not for the clients (10.04/12.10) that have squid-deb-proxy-client installed and listening on right port 8000 right? In this case, if client 10.04 does a sudo apt-get update && upgrade, he will use the internet bandwidth to download from internet packages and not the onces cache on the 12.04x64 right?

Comment: Correct, the first 10.04 client will hit the internet first, and then the next ones will hit the cache, in this case having 12.04's debs in the cache won't help until at least one 10.04 client updates.

Comment: But that will require me to also install squid-deb-proxy server on the 10.04 right? So this will eliminate single ubuntu 12.04x64 as the sole squid-deb-proxy server for all ubuntu versions right?

Comment: No, you need to install the _client_ on the 10.04 machine, the server will serve up to any client that is listening, so you only need one of those.

Comment: So what I am understanding from you is that once the 10.04 client hits the internet and downloads/caches the 10.04 debs it will automatically sends the cached debs to the squid-deb-proxy server which is in this case 12.04x64?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Thanks! One last thing to be aware of the ports. They uploads of debs from clients to server is going to be thru port 8000 too?