# How can i avoid downloading packages every-time I install my Ubuntu?

Tags: downloads, packaging

Every time i install Ubuntu on a computer I have to download the applications/packages
with total size of 1.5~2GB and it took lots of my network bandwidth & time!!

How can I avoid downloading the same packages that i am downloading everytime i.e I just need to have an archive of packages which have been downloaded once and stored somewhere, and use/install them when I install a new Ubuntu? (like I did in Windows - The setup files... )

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [apt-cache-ng](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/) on one of your computers and setup apt to proxy into the apt-cache-ng server instead going to the Internet every time, the files are cached and delivered by the local computer.

The server can easily be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install apt-cacher-ng
```

The client (i.e the machine being installed) can be set up by creating a file containing

```
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://CacheServerIp:3142"; };
```

in the directory

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own local repository.
The repository will be updated with the new packages from the internet periodically and you can use the repository to install new computers in your LAN. This will cause network-traffic but no internet-traffic during the installation and it is faster..

Refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository

Answer (score 1):

I'm Noob. Just install APTonCD. This application will make backup on your updates pakages and you will be able to install it on other ubuntu. just my $0.02! Hope it help.

Comment: Great point - not all places may have network access, so an offline CD source is also a workable option.

Answer (score 0):

Install `squid-deb-proxy` on one of your computers (which will then act as a package proxy server), and install `squid-deb-proxy-client` on the others. The clients will automatically detect the presence of a proxy server (using Avahi), and will load the packages from there; in case the clients are taken to a different network (which is often the case with laptops), they will automatically switch to direct download.

Comment: This is essentially the same solution that @txwikinger offers here: http://askubuntu.com/a/282892/1319 , but has the advantage of client autoconfiguration (so updating works even if there isn't a deb-proxy on the current network).