# How to copy all "apt-get update" cache

Tags: apt, cache

How can I copy all `apt-get update` cache to another computer, so that it doesn't need be updated again and again after new installation?

Comment: Yes Is there any solution ???

Comment: every package need a repo update

Comment: Wouldn't a apt-get update take less time than a copy of the cache would? :P

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, you could copy the content of `/var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` into the other `/var/cache/apt/archives/` as root...

But if this is anything but a one-off, I would definitely suggest one of the various caching server options that are out there so you only ever have to download these updates once:

- [Apt-Cacher-Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server)
- [AptProxy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptProxy)
- [Squid+Apache and more](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan)