# Apt-cacher-ng: Is there a way to avoid duplicating /var/cache/apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, apt-cacher-ng, squid-deb-proxy

I know `apt-cacher-ng` is duplicating the data in `/var/cache/apt`.
Is there a way to tell it to use `/var/cache/apt`, or it isn't doable due to permissions?
Mi partition has little space. I could indeed make apt-cacher-ng use other partition, but it seems to me like I am wasting space.
Not sure if [squid-deb-proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan) does the same thing, duplicating the packages.
I just want it to use `/var/cache/apt`. If it is not doable I will understand :)
Thanks!