# How to mirror only required update's from apt-update repo

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, apt-mirror

Mirroring apt takes 100 gb of data...its not possible with my slow connection.

is there any better way to update all hosts using minimum bandwidth consumption?

Am running ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04 LTS servers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to cache apt downloads on a LAN?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan)

Comment: It doesn't download 100 GB every time it updates. Only for the first run. After that it downloads only things that have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use apt-cacher.

Here is a link to the wiki page:
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server