# Copy updated & upgraded package to new linux system

Tags: upgrade

I have a Linux system with updated and upgraded packages and i install new linux system in another disk i want to copy the updated and upgraded packages from the old system to the new system to avoid make apt update & apt upgrade in the new system . which folders can I copy it from old system to New system

Comment: Your thought is not completed? Related: [Backup/clone live to a new partition which can be booted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/backup-clone-live-to-a-new-partition-which-can-be-booted/1028605#1028605)

Comment: It's much faster to run the two mentioned commands than to perform the complicated task of copying files from many directories to the new system and probably ending up with a corrupted package database. My advice: keep it simple and run apt update & apt upgrade.

Comment: The `apt upgrade` command changes various files in various folders not only for the operating system but also for the installed applications. So, finding out exactly which files were "updated" is not simple. You may want to check out [Best way to cache apt downloads on a LAN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan) if you have multiple Ubuntu computers to update in a local area network.